# Hiding a text field in html is taking space

Tags: html

I am trying to hide an input field with an id of `site_id`. When I run the code, the field is hidden, but still takes up space.

```
<!--MANAGEMENT DEPARTMENT-->
<div class="tab-pane" id="department">  
    <div class="container center" id="dept-container">
        <h3 class="center">Departments Management</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table-manage-user">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Name</label></td>
                <td><label>Email</label></td>
                <td><label>Phone</label></td>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <form method="post" action="temp.php">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" autofocus name="depart_name" id="depart_name" required aria-required="true"></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="display: none" class="site_id" placeholder="siteID" disabled="disabled"name="site_id" id="site_id"  value= ""></td>
                <td><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus name="depart_email" id="depart_email" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" autofocus name="depart_phone" id="depart_phone" required aria-required="true"></td>
                </form>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to hide it without taking up any space?

Comment: Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. Or change `type` to `hidden`.

Comment: Add `display: none` on `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to change the input type to hidden, but to avoid extra cell you should move the "display:none" to the td tag:

```
            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" class="site_id" placeholder="siteID" disabled="disabled"name="site_id" id="site_id"  value= ""></td>
```

Comment: or not put your hidden input element in the table, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add the style to the `<td>` tag instead.

You're not hiding the tag, so it is still "taking up space."

Also, it is good practice to use CSS instead of hard-coding styles into tags, as it allows for easier maintenance (say you wanted to change the 'hidden' tags to grayed-out, you just change the class style and all your pages will be updated):

### HTML

```
<td class="inactive"> <input ... /> </td>
```

### CSS

```
.inactive { display:none }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the `input`, hide the `td`, as the code below:

**HTML**:

```
<!--MANAGEMENT DEPARTMENT-->
<div class="tab-pane" id="department">  
    <div class="container center" id="dept-container">
        <h3 class="center">Departments Management</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table-manage-user">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Name</label></td>
                <td><label>Email</label></td>
                <td><label>Phone</label></td>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <form method="post" action="temp.php">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" autofocus name="depart_name" id="depart_name" required aria-required="true"></td>
                <td id="site_id_td"><input type="text" class="site_id" placeholder="siteID" disabled="disabled"name="site_id" id="site_id"  value= ""></td>
                <td><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus name="depart_email" id="depart_email" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" autofocus name="depart_phone" id="depart_phone" required aria-required="true"></td>
                </form>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#site_id_td").hide();
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9DeRd/) is the JSFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code in  tag of table

```
<td style="display: none"> </td>
```

So the space will be removed.
Hope this helps....

Comment: your code will still render the table cell, which is the OP's actual problem.

Comment: @user3830694 as i firstly thought , he need to just hide the input field, thats why i answered with that. Hope you understands... It's not about dont know , its about mus-understanding. Mr perfect